# Magento 2 QR Code image for 2 Factor Authentication broken on Magento 2 Admin Login

Tags: admin, magento2.4, two-factor-authentication

We have an issue with a new Magento 2.4.2 site after migrating from M1 and activating 2 Factor Authentication. The QR code will not load and just displays as a broken image.

[image: Magento 2 Factor Authenticaion Image]

Comment: Any One found the solution ?

Comment: Anyone have a legit. answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be caused by an erroneous newline being added to all output.
If you inspect the page source (right click => view source) on any page and you see this, then you have the same issue.

[image: view source example]

To find the offending file we used [Magento's coding standards](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/coding-standards/code-standard-php.html) with [PHP_CoderSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer)

```bash
magento@12389-php-fpm:~/htdocs$ ./vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=Magento2 app

FILE: /app/path/to/file.php
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 1 ERROR AND 2 WARNINGS AFFECTING 3 LINES
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2 | ERROR   | [ ] The opening PHP tag must be the first content in the file
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHPCBF CAN FIX THE 2 MARKED SNIFF VIOLATIONS AUTOMATICALLY
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Unfortunately CodeSniifer was unable to fix the file automatically, but it was a case of changing

```php
  
<?php
```

to

```php
<?php
```

Then flushing cache.

**N.B** if the above doesn't find an error for you, you may need to also check vendor, though fixing an issue with a module in vendor would require assistance from the vendor or a patch.